# react send data from child component to parent

Tags: reactjs

**Main.js (Parent)**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import Books from './Books'
import Navbar from './Navbar'
import AddBook from './AddBook';
import BookDetail from './BookDetail';

const Main = () => {
    let [books, setBooks] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-books')
            .then(res => {
                setBooks(books = res.data)
            })
    })

    return (
        <Router>
            <div>
                <Navbar title='LunaBooks'/>
                <div className='container'>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path='/' >
                            <Books books={books} />
                        </Route>

                        <Route path='/add-book' >
                            <AddBook />
                        </Route>

                        <Route path='/details/' >
                            <BookDetail bookName={} /> // put the bookName from Books.js here <----
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Main
```

**Books.js (Child)**

```
import React, { Component, useState } from 'react'
import BookDetail from './BookDetail'

const Books = ({books}) => {
    let [bookName, setBookName] = useState('')  // send the bookname to Main.js

    const SendBookDetails = e => {
        let bookName = e.target.value
        setBookName(bookName = bookName)
    }


    return (
        <div>
            <div className='books'>
                {books.map(book => (
                    <div className='book'> 
                        <h2>{book.name}</h2>
                        <p>Author: <a href='#'>{book.author}</a></p>
                        <button className="btn" value={book.name} onClick={SendBookDetails}>View Details</button>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Books
```

> To put it simply, I want to send the bookName that is located in Books.js and put in the Main.js so that I can pass it in BookDetail.js, I know how to do in the reverse way but this is just confusing me for some reason... I'm pretty new to react so please bear with me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a selectedBook state in the parent.

```
const [selectedBook, setSelectedBook] = useState()
```

Pass a callback function as a prop "onBookSelect" to the child.

```
<Books books={books} onBookSelect={(book) => { setSelectedBook(book) } />
```

Then in the child call the callback function with new value. in your SendBookDetails  function.

```
const Books = ({books, onBookSelect}) => {
  //...
  const SendBookDetails = e => {
        let bookName = e.target.value
        setBookName(bookName)
        onBookSelect(bookName)
    }
```

Then pass that state to the props of your book details component.

```
<BookDetail bookName={selectedBook} />
```